# deploying environment specific .htaccess files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, .htaccess, deployment, capistrano

I have a .htaccess file with a line that specifies the environment for the application I am running (staging, production etc..)

```
RackEnv staging
```

Whats the best way to handle this for environment specific deployments with capistrano and capistrano-ext?

somehow write to it dynamically in a capistrano task?
symbolically link to an existing, shared .htaccess that is specific for each deployment, much in the same way as you do for database.yml?

are there any other options? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than put this in your .htaccess file you could add it to your apache config file for that app, typically this would be /etc/apache2/sites-available/yoursite

Here is an example of a file such as this with your setup ...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  yoursite.com
            ServerAlias yoursite.* 

    DocumentRoot /var/www/httpdocs/current/public

    <Directory /var/www/httpdocs/current/>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    RackEnv staging
    RailsEnv staging

    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your deploy.rb file separate out the site specific stuff, like this ...

```
task :staging do
    set :application, "yoursite"
    set :repository, "yoursite.git"
    set :branch, "master"
    set :deploy_to, "/var/www/httpdocs/currebt"
    server "staging.yoursite.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
    set :rails_env, "staging"
end
```

If all that is setup you can then run

```
cap staging deploy
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I have shared hosting, so this solution would be difficult, however I will contact my host to see if they could set it up.